# How can i translate my feature matrix to weka language?

Tags: weka, svm

I need some help please.
Well, i have some feature vectores from 2 classes (2 differents movements of upper limb).   Now i need to put my feature matrix (all feature vectors) in weka to classify my movements, specifically with SVM algorithm. But i never worked with weka before, or with java or with format arff. How can i translate my feature matrix to weka language?

Thank you very much. I will apreciate all help

Lilia

Comment: Worth noting that weka is not a language, but a library built on top of Java, the language. Arff is just a format that weka uses. There's a good example of converting a csv to arff here: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Converting+CSV+to+ARFF

Answer (score 1):

Realized it should probably be a full answer, but there are a number of great documents out there that detail the .arff file format. Since you already have feature vectors it's worth just using each entry in that feature vector as a different numerical output.

There's a good explanation of the Arff format here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

There's a Java example showing how to convert a csv to an arff file programatically:
http://weka.wikispaces.com/Converting+CSV+to+ARFF

And there's even an online tool that will do most of it for you (I don't really recommend this as it makes sometimes critical mistakes):
http://slavnik.fe.uni-lj.si/markot/csv2arff/csv2arff.php

Though if all you want to do is run some regression, weka will let you do that without converting anything to arff.

Comment: This helps a lot. But i'm with some difficulty to define my attributes, are they my feature vectors? Thank you

Comment: Each feature in your feature vector is an attribute.

Comment: I everyone, please help me.
 when i try open the file with weka, this error appears:
'wrong number of values. Read 3, expected 1, read Token [EOL], line 9'

i thing everything is okay, what´s up?

Comment: @LiliaJorge look at line 9 of your file. It looks like you have a single quote where you shouldn't